# Passing or setting password parameter to mercurial during docker build

Tags: ubuntu, docker, mercurial

I'm trying to setup a docker image, and my codebase resides in bitbucket. The problem here is mercurial asks for password to clone the repository. After researching a bit, found out that during `docker build` process, it doesn't allow the user to enter anything. The command stops just after `hg clone` asking for authorisation. Any workarounds ? Thanks

Sample dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs npm git git-core
RUN apt-get -y install mercurial
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
RUN npm install -g bower
RUN npm install -g grunt-cli
RUN hg clone <repository>
```

Comment: As a work-around, could I suggest running the Docker build from within a build server like Jenkins, which has a Mercurial plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either configure your credentials(ssh keys) or pass it through the Mercurial command line.

http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/remote/#caching-of-http-s-credentials

If you do not want to have your ssh keys saved in a Docker image, you can instead perform those steps manually in a container (clone using
http://user:password@host/repo).
Then commit your container to an image.

ie.

```
host$ docker run -it --name clonedRepoContainer ubuntu bash 
container$ apt-get update
container$ apt-get install -y nodejs npm git git-core
container$ apt-get -y install mercurial
container$ ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
container$ npm install -g bower
container$ npm install -g grunt-cli
container$ hg clone http://user:password@host/repo
host$ docker commit clonedRepoContainer finalImage
```